# Erlang ChicagoBoss access external files from URL

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

How to access external files from other servers using CB ?

```
-module(example_index_controller, [Req, SessionID]).
-compile([export_all]).
index('GET', []) ->
CSV = http:request(body, {"https://www.example.com/catalog.csv", []}, [{ssl,[{verify,0}]}],
{ok, [{data, CSV  }]}.
```

I found that to make ssl working inside console I need to do:

```
application:start(inets).
application:start(ssl).
application:start(crypto).
application:start(asn1).
application:start(public_key).
application:start(ssl).
```

I do not know how to implement this into CB or check if this is already there.

Comment: Do you mean  download the file?